# How to provide stdin for doctests?

Tags: haskell, testing, io, stdin, doctest

I want to create an example in doctest for using `getLine`. However, when I run the test, it does not terminate:

```
{- |
>>> getLine
>>> Hello, World!
"Hello, World!"
-}
module MyModule where
```

How to provide custom input for doctest?

Comment: Looks like you can't provide input to `doctest`. Probably worth opening an issue on the github repository: https://github.com/sol/doctest/issues